# Python - TypeError: Must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a part of a project in which I have to list all the people in a class, and their ages, one by one. The code is as follows:

```
def optionThree():
    print("You have chosen the Programming and Robotics option.")
    stuList=[]
    name=None
    while name!=("END"):
        stuList.append(name)
        name=str(input("""
Please enter the name of all the students in your P&R class, one at a time.
Enter the word 'END' in full caps to end the procedure.
        """))      

    count=len(stuList)
    age=[]
    stuNum=(0)
    for count in range(0,count):
        nameCall=stuList[stuNum]
        stuNum=(stuNum+1)
        stuAge=int(input("Please enter the age of the student named "+(nameCall)+"please."))
        age.append(stuAge)
    print("You have given ages for everyone in your P&R class.")
    stuNum=(0)
    for count in range(0,count):
        print("The student,",(stuList[stuNum]),", is",(age[stuNum])," years old.")
        stuNum=stuNum+1

optionThree()
```

When I run the code, it gives me an error for the line:

```
stuAge=int(input("Please enter the age of the student named "+(nameCall)+"please."))
```

saying "TypeError: Must be str, not NoneType". What specifically am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you started with name = None and then made it the first entry in stuList.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I probably would have spend another half an hour on the problem if it wasn't for you. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for providing a nicely written question with all needed information to solve it.